# q-Strong Bilinear Diffie-Hellman

Tags: hardness-assumptions

I'm having trouble finding the *first* paper that introduced the $q$-Strong Bilinear Diffie-Hellman ($q$-SBDH) assumption which, roughly speaking, is:

Let $\mathbb{G},\mathbb{G}_T$ be two groups of order $p$, with a bilinear map $e$ from $\mathbb{G}$ to $\mathbb{G}_T$.
Let $s \stackrel{$}{\leftarrow} \mathbb{Z}^*_p$ be a trapdoor. Given $pp = \langle g, g^s, g^{s^2},..., g^{s^q} \rangle \in  \mathbb{G}^{q+1}$, an adversary has negligible probability of finding $\langle c, e(g, g)^{\frac{1}{s+c}} \rangle$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z_p} \setminus \{-s\}$.

Some papers seem to point to Dan Boneh's ["Short signatures without random oracles and the SDH assumption in bilinear groups"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-007-9005-7) (Journal of Cryptography, 2008). However, as far as I've read the paper, only $q$-SDH is defined there, not $q$-SBDH.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The q-SDH assumption is about groups with a bilinear pairing. This is clearly stated in the cited article.

Comment: Eh, right. $q$-SDH and $q$-SBDH are assumptions in groups with pairings, but they are _different assumptions._ In $q$-SDH, it's hard to find $\langle c, g^{\frac{1}{s+c}} \rangle$, while in $q$-SBDH it's hard to find  $\langle c, e(g,g)^{\frac{1}{s+c}} \rangle$.

Comment: Ok, maybe this one: https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/172.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly? They define $q$-BDHI which asks the adversary to find $e(g,g)^{\frac{1}{x}}$, which is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation, the earliest paper I could find that introduces $q$-Strong Bilinear Diffie-Hellman was [Reducing Trust in the PKG in Identity Based Cryptosystems](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-74143-5_24) by *Vipul Goyal* in CRYPTO 2007.